# Why is this s3 Bucket policy invalid?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1612574490300",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1612574488073",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:258977512672:instance/i-041123c1993c370ba"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

response is Invalid Principal.  I dont see why it's invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An EC2 instance isn't a valid principal. I think what you actually need to do here is use the ARN of the IAM role assigned to the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify following `Principal` in a policy

- AWS account and root user
- IAM users
- Federated users (using web identity or SAML federation)
- IAM roles
- Assumed-role sessions
- AWS services
- Anonymous users (not recommended)

[S3 Documentation Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html)

[AWS JSON policy elements: Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html)

If you wanna give that instant access to the bucket then you can use [Instance profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html)